# C: Correct Increment of uint8 big endian string

Tags: string, increment, uint32

is there a correct way to increment a uint8 string in big endian format?
For example i have:

```
uint8 test[] = {0,0,0,1};

test[3]++; //works
```

but is also somehow an increment with an typecast in this way possible?

```
 *test = (uint32) *test+1; //doesnt work... Only the first test[0] will be incremented...
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
((uint32_t*)test)++;
```

But this still operates in native byte order.

If you have a buffer  in network order, you should do this:

```
uint32_t *p = (uint32_t*)test;
uint32_t temp = ntohl(*p);
temp++;
*p = htonl(temp);
```